# Unable to get value from another contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity, parity, geth, quorum

I am facing a head scratching issue.  I have created two contracts UserRole which has a map of username to a role and a Base contract that has a modifier which checks if the role is < 10.

So I deploy the first UserRole contract first and then I called the set function with the parameters _username = "jamesbond" and _role=7.

After the transaction is mined I call the getRole passing _username = "jamesbond" and I get back 7.

Now I deploy Base and pass the address of the the UserRole contract that I deployed earlier.  I call the testModifier function and I pass it _username = "jamesbond".  I expect that I get the value 7 back.

I tested this on http://remix.ethereum.org first.  Then I tried it on quorum and parity.  On remix it works as expected but on both quorum and parity I do not get any values back.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract UserRole {
    address owner;

    mapping (string => uint8) userRoles;

    constructor() 
        public
    {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function set(string _username, uint8 _role) 
        public
        returns (bool sucesss)
    {
        userRoles[_username] = _role;
        return true;
    }

    function getRole(string _username) 
        public
        view
        returns (uint8 _role)
    {
        return userRoles[_username];
    }
}

contract Base {
    address owner;
    UserRole userRole;
    address public userRoleAddress;

    constructor(address _t) 
        public
    {
        owner = msg.sender;
        userRoleAddress = _t;
        userRole = UserRole(_t);
    }


    modifier isAuthorized(string _username) {
        uint8 role = 5;
        require(role < 10);
        _;
    }

    function testModifier(string _username)
        public
        isAuthorized(_username)
        view
        returns (uint8 result)
    {
        return userRole.getRole(_username);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issues when compiling the contract with [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org). 
The solution is as follows:

1. Install solcjs using

   `npm install -g solc` 
   It will provide executable binary of solcjs.

   2.Create two file named `UserRole.sol` and `Base.sol` and copy the respective code in the files. Compile both the contracts using solcjs compiler (binary installed in your system.).

   `solcjs -o output --bin --abi UserRole.sol`

   `solcjs -o output --bin --abi Base.sol`
2. It will produce two abi and two bin file inside `output` folder.
3. Use these abi and bin of respective contracts to create similar script like `web3deploy` and deploy them in quorum or parity.

This will work.